# "There is no editor available for ../Form1.vb" error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010, forms

I was happily using VB.NET, saved, and, well, there was a blackout.

Probably lucky? Well, now I open my project just fine, double click the Form1.vb and.... "There is no editor available for ../Form1.vb, make sure the application for the file type (.vb) is installed."

.......... Did something go wrong with my project? Is it *dead*?

Windows 7, Visual Basic 2010 Express.

What should I do?

Comment: It seems it is only my Form1.vb file. I can create other forms and they work just fine. Daaaaamn!! What do I do? Is.. is there a way to at least get the code of Form1.vb?

Comment: this happens once to me, because of bad sectors in my hard disk. there are many recovery tools available to recover data. but not sure if there's a bad sector. but i was lucky that time and got it back.

Comment: Mind telling me how you got it back? It seems I can't see the code nor designer of my Form...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to imagine what you're seeing. I've seen plenty of cases where the design view won't open for whatever reason, but I've never been unable to view the *code* for the form.

First thing to try is navigating to your project folder in Windows Explorer, right-clicking on the `Form1.vb` file, and trying to open it in Notepad. This is pretty much the ultimate test. **If you can open it in Notepad, your work is salvageable. If not, the file is corrupted and your best bet is to start over.** I suppose if you *really* feel that you have a lot invested, you could try various file recovery techniques, but considering it's a single form file, I seriously doubt it's worth the time or expense.

If that succeeds, and you *can* open the file in Notepad, select all the code and copy it to the clipboard. Now go back into Visual Studio, and add a new `Form` to your project. Delete everything in the new form's code file and paste the salvaged code from your original form back in. You still won't be able to open the form in the designer though, and you'll likely be missing references to all of your controls. Ignore all those squiggly underlines for now.

To fix that, you need to go back to Windows Explorer, and find a file named `Form1.Designer.vb`. This is the partial class that the designer saves information into; it contains declarations for all of your controls and the properties you set for those controls at design time. Just as before, right-click on this file and open it in Notepad. Select everything and copy it to the clipboard. Now go back to Visual Studio, and click on the "Show All Files" button at the top of the Solution Explorer (hover over them to read the ToolTips). You'll see a bunch of extra junk show up, but what you're primarily interested in are the drop-down arrows that just appeared to the side of every `Form` class. Expand the new form you added in the previous step, and find it's `.Designer` file. Delete everything that's in there now, and paste in the code from your salvaged form's `.Designer` file.

You now have an *exact* copy of your old form in your project. You can delete that old, corrupted form file, because you're no longer using it. You'll also probably want to change the name of the new file itself by right-clicking on it in the Solution Explorer—right now, it's named `Form1` just like your old form, because it's an exact copy of that form. The code says it's name is `Form1` and couldn't care less about your file name. Clean and rebuild your project, and if things go your way, everything should be back to normal.

Comment: I went to Form1.vb, opened with Notepad, and got a blank file (it is 27kb, but the file consists of blank space)..... therefore, I assume my file is corrupted and dead? Hmmm.... that is quite a problem. That form's code was my whole application actually. You mentioned other file recovery techniques? Could explain about them please? Thank you, I will go cry on a corner meanwhile :)

Comment: @Omega: File recovery isn't really my cup of tea. I mentioned that only because I know they exist. Super User is a better place to ask about how one might go about recovering data from a corrupted file. Here, people will just tell you things like "You should have been using source control". It's really weird that the file should be corrupted to the extent you can't view it in Notepad; I've never seen that before, but I wouldn't know what else to try were it to happen to me.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll go take a look there. Maybe consider start over (again. yeah, don't ask =/) with source control and everything.... I mean, this application was hard to develop because I am still a newbie at VB.NET, but now I have the knowledge for doing things a bit faster and better with less references now......... I hope so. Thank you.

Comment: Question asked. If you'd like to keep track of it for whatever reason, here is the link: http://superuser.com/questions/242219/recovering-corrupted-vb-net-form-file, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

The same thing just occurred to me but I couldn't get it fixed trying the previous answers. For some reason, one of my references `Microsoft.Office.Core` had a yellow exclamation point on it.

### Simple Solution

- **Solution Explorer**

  - Expand References
  - Right click on the item with "Yellow Triangle w/ "!" point"
  - Select "Remove"
- **Open the "Build" Menu at the top**

  - Select Rebuild "filename"

Once this was done, I could open my forms correctly.

Comment: Of all the possible solutions yours is the one that helped me. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too. Really obscure, chasing the wrong rabbit kind of bug, as I spent too long repairing Visual Studio first which did nothing.

Comment: I had this happen, except all of my references had the yellow triangle. I either double clicked one, or tried to right click it, or something like that, and then they all changed back to normal, and then I could open the vb file.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7/ Vista:
Try right clicking the .vb file and selecting the "Previous versions" tab. When the list has loaded (if it has) select the most recent file from the list and select "Restore". Now reload your project, try doing this with all of the form files, e.g. "Form1.resx" and "Form1.designer.vb" and "Form1.vb" and then reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

It implies that the file is corrupted.Replace an uncorrupted copy of that file in the corresponding directory and then try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was from a bad reference to Excel caused by copying the project from a Win7 machine to a Win8 machine probably.

Open the solution explorer and expand the references You will see two references with the yellow exclamation mark icon beside them indicating a problem - Microsoft.Office.Core - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Right click on both these icons and click remove Your form should load now, if not, save the project, close it then reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too . when i restart Visual Studio the form create successfully and show it's designer.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the Form with a different version of VS, other than 2012 (eg VS 2010, VS 2013, VS 2015; I've used VS 2015). Save the Form in the solution, open the solution with VS 2012 and include the form in the solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you need :

1) NotePad++

And you should follow this simple steps :

1) Close Visual Studio .

2) Go to the Backup Folder of your VS version usually in : "C:\Users(your user name)\Documents\Visual Studio (year)\Backup Files\your project or application name" .

3) Open the last Backup file of your corrupted file , usually the name format is : "Recovered-month.-day-year-time.(Your File Name).cs" with NotePad++ , and copy the source code .

4) Go to your corrupted file in the project folder and open it with NotePad++ , Edit => Select All => Past the source code and Save .

5) Go to windows start list and search for : "Visual Studio Tools" folder , open it and double click on : "Developer Command Prompt for VS(year)" .

6) Write this two codes in the Developer Command Prompt : "devenv.exe /setup" and then "devenv /resetskippkgs" .

7) Open your project .

Note : if this didn't work for you try to do the steps before in this arrangement :

1) => 2) => 3) => 4) => 7) => 1) => 5) => 6) => 7)

and your problem will be fixed .

It works 100% for me , i hope this will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the security permissions on the form affected.  Right click the file,  go to properties then security and change the access ability to everyone.